# .js no encuentro el error

Tags: javascript, html, div

estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema y al presionar el boton "baja de usuario" debería mostrar u ocultar un formulario, funciona con todos los demas menos con este en particular. dejo el código a continuacion.

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#ocultaraltausuario").hide();    /*Esconde formulario alta de usuario. */
    $("#ocultaraltausuario").hide();

$("#mostraraltausuario").click(function(){
     $("#ocultaraltausuario").toggle();

})

$("#ocultaraltaequipo").hide();     /*Esconde formulario alta de equipo. */
    $("#ocultaraltaequipo").hide();

$("#mostraraltaequipo").click(function(){
     $("#ocultaraltaequipo").toggle();

})

$("#ocultarbajaequipo").hide();     /*Esconde formulario baja de equipo */
    $("#ocultarbajaequipo").hide();

$("#mostrarbajaequipo").click(function(){
     $("#ocultarbajaequipo").toggle();

})

$("#ocultarbajausuario").hide();    /*Esconde formulario baja de usuario */
    $("#ocultarbajausuario").hide();

$("mostrarbajausuario").click(function(){
     $("#ocultarbajausuario").toggle();

})

});
```

desde ya muchas gracias. !

Comment: Te falta un numeral (`#`) en `$("mostrarbajausuario")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//en esta parte mostrarbajadeusuario te falta agregar el numeral (#) 
$("#mostrarbajausuario").click(function(){
     $("#ocultarbajausuario").toggle();

})
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Una respuesta con solo código se considera de baja calidad. De hecho, podría incluso pensarse que solo has copiado y pegado el código de la pregunta